# Check if a sentence contains a number and print sentences with number

Tags: python-2.7

I want to check whether a sentence in the file containing the number and if that contain I want to print that sentences.

I'm a beginner in python and I need some help with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Please review the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `x` as a placeholder for your file. You would want to replace that with `myfile.readlines()` or whatever you would use to loop over each line in your file.

```
x = ['My placeholder file' , 'that contains sentences', 'with and without numbers', 'There should be 2 sentences with numbers.' , 'There should be 3 setences without numbers']
for eachLine in x:
  if any(char.isdigit() for char in eachLine):
    print eachLine
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand this question, because you are confusing me with whether it is a single sentence or many, also how many you want to print, and whether it is a specific number or not. However, I can barely understand it and this is what I got from it (look for how to make good questions anyways)

I think you want to know how to find something in a sentence or list of sentences and print it. That is done like this:

```
string = "Whatever string you want this to be, blah blah blah, etc.
for b in string: #This will look for every character in the string making b that character
    if b == 'b':  #If the character is 'b'
        print b  #It will print the character
                 #If not, it will move on to the next character
```

That is how you can find a word in a string. If you want multiple strings, just make string a list:

```
strings = ['one string', 'two string', 'three string', 'etc']
for b in strings:   #This will look for every string in the strings making b that string
    for c in b:     #This will look for every character in the b making c that character
       if c == 's':  #If that character is 's'
            print b #It will print the character
                    #If not, it will move on to the next character
```